# How to play a ringtone using the Alarm volume with setAudioAttributes?

Tags: android, audio

So I'm trying to wrap my head around Audio Attributes. Here's what I have so far:

```
// alarm.getSound() will return a proper URI to pick a ringtone
Ringtone tone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, alarm.getSound());
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    AudioAttributes aa = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setFlags(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM | AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
        .build();
    tone.setAudioAttributes(aa);
} else {
    tone.setStreamType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
}
tone.play();
```

[This page](https://source.android.com/devices/audio/attributes.html) talks about Audio Attributes and their "Compatibility Mappings." If I was previously using `setStreamType(TYPE_ALARM)` (like I am above) then it will set the `CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION` and `USAGE_ALARM` flags. I want to get away from `setStreamType` so I was thinking that if I manually set those flags (like I am above) then when the ringtone plays it will use the Alarm volume. Well, it doesn't seem to work like that.

The above code still rings using my Nexus 6's Media volume instead of the Alarm volume. I'm on 6.0 with build MRA68N. What could I do different to use the Alarm volume?

Comment: Since it was not explicitly stated in either answer, those parameters as flags are ignored. It will always play at full volume through the default stream. Setting them in the appropriate `setter` **does** resolve it, though.

Comment: This answer might help folks looking here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53390067/826946

Answer (score 12):

Tested on Moto G Android 6.0

```
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            AudioAttributes aa = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                    .build();
            ringtone.setAudioAttributes(aa);
        } else {
            ringtone.setStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The response here helped but didn't work for me. I opened my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50881732/playing-sound-on-the-alarm-channel-on-android/50881793#50881793) to resolve it.

Here is my working solution.

```
mediaPlayerScan = new MediaPlayer();
try {
  mediaPlayerScan.setDataSource(getContext(),
          Uri.parse(getString(R.string.res_path) + R.raw.scan_beep));

  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    mediaPlayerScan.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
            .build());
  } else {
    mediaPlayerScan.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
  }
  mediaPlayerScan.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```